# How to run java code from another java program?

Tags: java, class, input, calling-convention

i have this code in file `Abc.java` and want to run it from another Java program. I tried but it is not taking user input.

```
public class Abc
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int s;
        System.out.println("Enter a value..");
        s = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" "+s);
    }
}
```

which approach I can use to accomplish my task?

Comment: just call the main method Abc.main(new String[0]);, in other words call the main method of the second class.

Comment: Something like `Abc.main(new String[0]);` I would imagine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
public class Xyz {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Abc.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can call the `main` method of the second class because it is like any other static method.

For example

```
Abc.main(new String[0]);
```